# Github + Netbeans + SourceTree ERROR en Push

Tags: java, netbeans, github, sourcetree

No me permite hacer push alguien podria explicarme porque?
[image: Commits]

[image: Error al realizar un Push]

Despues de hacer commit y hacer pull

Comment: puedes poner todos los comandos que hiciste?

Comment: el path 'build/*' indica algún tipo de compilación local, que al parecer también está en el repositorio, eso puede generar conflictos todo el tiempo ( tu build es diferente al build de otro dev y diferente al que está en el repo ), lo mas conveniente en esos casos es agregar la carpeta de builds locales al gitignore así no se trackean

Comment: parace que master está más actualizado que tu branch

Answer (score 1):

Buenas.
Para hacer un *"push"* a un repositorio debes tener cambios confirmados en un "*commit*". Ahora si no confirmaste todos los cambios en un *commit* no puedes hacer *pull* o dicho de otra forma, "bajar" los cambios de tu servidor remoto. Esto sucede por que al bajar los cambios, sobreescribirías tus cambios locales no preparados, por lo tanto, puedes:

- Hacer un *commit* con los cambios que aún no preparas usando el comando `git add` y luego `git commit`
  [Como hacer un commit](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Fundamentos-de-Git-Guardando-cambios-en-el-repositorio)
- Ignorar los archivos cambiados no preparados a la lista de archivos que no son parte del control de version, agregandolos a la lista de .gitignore
  [Como ignorar archivos](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Fundamentos-de-Git-Guardando-cambios-en-el-repositorio#Ignorando-archivos)
- Descartar los cambios que no han sido preparados con `git checkout -- <file> ...`
  [Como deshacer cambios en un archivo](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Fundamentos-de-Git-Deshaciendo-cosas#Deshaciendo-la-modificaci%C3%B3n-de-un-archivo)

Debido a que usas SourceTree:

- Para hacer commit

  1. Haz click en el icono de *commit* en la barra de herramientas.
  2. En la ventana de *"Unstaged files"*, clickea todos los archivos que vas a incluir en el commit.
  3. Ingresa el mensaje del commit
  4. Haz click en *commit* para preparar tus cambios.

     > *Puedes ver [How to commit on SourceTree](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/commit-push-and-pull-a-repository-on-sourcetree-785616067.html) para tener mayor información.*
- Para ignorar archivos

  1. Selecciona el archivo que quieres ignorar en la ventana de *"Unstaged files"*
  2. Haz click derecho sobre el archivo.
  3. Haz click sobre *"Stop Tracking"* en el menú contextual.
  4. Repite el proceso para hacer commit, pero esta vez agrega al commit el archivo **.gitignore** que contiene el nombre del archivo que ignoraste.
- Para descartar los cambios

  - Haz click en *"discard changes"* en el menú contextual del archivo.
  - O puedes hacer click derecho en el ultimo commit, luego en la opción 'Reset  to this commit' -'Hard - discard all working copy changes' .